# Solved Resources exceeded in GROUP BY, but I need to make it less expensive

Tags: google-bigquery

I solved the resources exceeded error when doing a GROUP BY EACH on a table with billions of rows.
However, the solution is very costly and I would like to bring those costs down.

The error was almost for certain not caused by a skewed grouping key, but by a too high cardinality of the grouping key (is there a fixed max?).

My solution:

```
SELECT key FROM
(SELECT key FROM [table] WHERE ABS(HASH(key)) % 4 = 0 GROUP EACH BY key),
(SELECT key FROM [table] WHERE ABS(HASH(key)) % 4 = 1 GROUP EACH BY key),
(SELECT key FROM [table] WHERE ABS(HASH(key)) % 4 = 2 GROUP EACH BY key),
(SELECT key FROM [table] WHERE ABS(HASH(key)) % 4 = 3 GROUP EACH BY key)
```

This works, but it reads my multi TB table multiple times, and I believe that's a bit pricey.
Is there a solution to cut down the costs?

Thanks, Ruben

Answer (score 6):

It reads the entire key column from "table" only once.